# /proc won't mount in kali linux running under Android

Tags: mount, kali-linux, android, proc

I'm now using kali Linux on termux. I had several problems like `/proc` is not mounted, `/proc` permission denied, etc.

`ps -aux`tells this:

```
> root@localhost:~# ps -aux
> 
> Error: /proc must be mounted
  To mount /proc at boot you need an /etc/fstab line like:
      proc   /proc   proc    defaults
  In the meantime, run "mount proc /proc -t proc"
```

Then I type `mount proc /proc - t proc` and this happens:

```
> root@localhost:~# mount proc /proc - t proc
> 
> Blockquotemount: /proc: mount(2) system call failed: Function not implemented.
```

I've also tried this too `pgrep lxcfs | xargs ps -f -p`. But nothing happens just this:

```
> root@localhost:~# pgrep lxcfs | xargs ps -f -p
> 
> Error: /proc must be mounted
  To mount /proc at boot you need an /etc/fstab line like:
      proc   /proc   proc    defaults
  In the meantime, run "mount proc /proc -t proc"
Error: /proc must be mounted
  To mount /proc at boot you need an /etc/fstab line like:
      proc   /proc   proc    defaults
  In the meantime, run "mount proc /proc -t proc"
```

Comment: Where's this Kali running? Are you running it with its standard kernel or not? Is this a full featured distro or some special build of it? Maybe it's docker, chroot or some kind of virtualization? How did you find yourself in a situation when `/proc` is not mounted?

Comment: @Artem it’s inside Termux on Android (which is probably the answer too, but I don’t know the details of what system calls are unavailable in such circumstances).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've just installed kali linux for termux, all is perfect, only /proc makes the problems. I was installing a git with python (kickthemout) and some errors occurred. When I run `python3 kickthemout.py' it tells me: `CRITICAL: Can't open /proc/net/dev` `CRITICAL: Can't open /proc/net/route` `CRITICAL: Can't open /proc/net/dev` and `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`        When I've searched related info about this, it says I have to `make /proc` or more things, but no one want work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal user account under Android is not allowed to mount anything anywhere, that would be a major security breach of the Android process isolation model.

This question should be asked somewhere else, e.g. https://android.stackexchange.com/ or https://forum.xda-developers.com/

You could root your device or use a VM (in case root is not available or you don't want to root). Here are some of the VMs I've found but I haven't tested any:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=studio.com.techriz.andronix
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula
- https://github.com/limboemu/limbo
- https://www.vmos.com/